# NoMethodError (undefined method `delete!' for nil:NilClass):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, heroku

I've been having a little issue with one of the apps I deployed to Heroku. Locally the app works fine, however on Heroku when I press a button that illicits an Ajax request I get a 500 error. The error is more specifically coming from a method within my controller called adding. Below are the logs from Heroku. Link to app: **https://ouinyc.herokuapp.com/**

**p.s to see the button that's giving the error you have to sign up, it's the two buttons below the stop and play buttons. **

**Curiously this is the error that stands out the most.**

```
  NoMethodError (undefined method `delete!' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:27:in `add_song'
```

**Below are some of the logs from Heroku**

```
2016-04-25T22:28:09.603876+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2016-04-25T22:28:09.603878+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2016-04-25T22:28:09.603874+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
2016-04-25T22:28:09.603875+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
2016-04-25T22:28:09.603879+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2016-04-25T22:28:09.603877+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
2016-04-25T22:28:09.603878+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
2016-04-25T22:28:09.603880+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
2016-04-25T22:28:09.603881+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-04-25T22:28:09.603881+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-04-25T22:28:11.095771+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.4ms)
2016-04-25T22:28:11.133322+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_audio_part.html.erb (7.2ms)
2016-04-25T22:28:11.133624+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 50ms (Views: 45.6ms | ActiveRecord: 3.8ms)
2016-04-25T22:28:11.107578+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (7.9ms)
2016-04-25T22:28:11.105471+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (3.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2016-04-25T22:28:11.120143+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (2.8ms)
2016-04-25T22:28:11.090234+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.6ms)
2016-04-25T22:28:11.081117+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/home" for 98.14.169.85 at 2016-04-25 22:28:11 +0000
2016-04-25T22:28:11.083194+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
2016-04-25T22:28:11.135758+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/home" host=ouinyc.herokuapp.com request_id=2be011c5-bff4-4ac6-8c0b-a681f7826f32 fwd="98.14.169.85" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=63ms status=200 bytes=7100
2016-04-25T22:28:23.338889+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/90210%20by%20Travis%20Scott.mp3" host=ouinyc.herokuapp.com request_id=b8770d58-15e2-40d9-a002-8ddd4fb9d4db fwd="98.14.169.85" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=166ms status=206 bytes=8526220
2016-04-25T22:28:41.387156+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/adding" host=ouinyc.herokuapp.com request_id=5c6bd67b-2c43-4086-90ff-b0fd0f524cd9 fwd="98.14.169.85" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=58ms status=500 bytes=1754
2016-04-25T22:28:41.375423+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/adding" for 98.14.169.85 at 2016-04-25 22:28:41 +0000
2016-04-25T22:28:41.377153+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#add_song as */*
2016-04-25T22:28:41.377249+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"data_value"=>"\"https://ouinyc.herokuapp.com/90210%20by%20Travis%20Scott.mp3\"", "authenticity_token"=>""}
2016-04-25T22:28:41.379928+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2016-04-25T22:28:41.381122+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2016-04-25T22:28:41.382269+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
2016-04-25T22:28:41.385136+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-04-25T22:28:41.385145+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `delete!' for nil:NilClass):
2016-04-25T22:28:41.385146+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:27:in `add_song'
2016-04-25T22:28:41.385147+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

**edit**
So the issue looks like it has to deal with the controller. That said I don't understand why it's saying the string object is empty.

**Controller**

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :js, :json, :html

     def get_songs()
          if user_signed_in?
                session[:user_id] = current_user.id
                present_user = User.find(session[:user_id])
                present_user = present_user.playlist.keys
            @songs = present_user
        respond_to do |format|
     format.json  { render :json => @songs}
      end
        end
        end



    def add_song()
           if user_signed_in?
                session[:user_id] = current_user.id
                present_user = User.find(session[:user_id])
                var = params[:data_value]
        var = var.sub!("http://localhost:3000/", "")
                var.delete!('""','')
           present_user.playlist.store(var, 1)      
                if present_user.save
                         render json: {success: "It works"}
   end    
      end
        end 

        def remove_song()
            if user_signed_in?
              session[:user_id] = current_user.id
              present_user = User.find(session[:user_id])
              var = params[:data_value] 
              present_user.playlist.delete(var)
       if present_user.save
                     render json: {success: "It works"}
        end 
        end 
        end

  def news
  end

  def home
   end


end
```

**ajax request**

```
$.ajax({
       url: "removing",
        type: "post",
       data: {data_value: JSON.stringify(player.src), authenticity_token: "<%= @form_auth_token %>" }
        }
   );
```

Comment: But what does the controller method look like? And why is it apparently trying to load the same user from the database twice? What is it trying to call `delete!` on?

Comment: please provide code for `app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb` around line 27

Comment: probably you contoller cant find an object, which you plan to delete.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ I just added the controller, and the ajax request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem code is the following, please dont' used without a real reason non-pure methods with `!`. And this line evaluated `var` to `nil`, since previous value of `var` has no prefixed line:

```
var = var.sub!("http://localhost:3000/", "")
```

so next `var.delete!` riases the exception:

Well the part of code:

```
var = params[:data_value]
var = var.sub!("http://localhost:3000/", "")
var.delete!('""','')
present_user.playlist.store(var, 1)
```

can be replaced with (since you are passing JSON encoded value):

```
song = JSON.parse((params[:data_value]).sub("localhost:3000/", ""),
   {:quirks_mode => true})'
present_user.playlist.store(song, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the line of code that helped.      'song = JSON.parse((params[:data_value]).sub("http://localhost:3000/", ""), {:quirks_mode => true})'